# How to grep strings from command output

Tags: linux, grep

```
NAME                READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
grepme              1/1       Running   0          20h
grepmetoo           1/1       Running   0          19h
```

Result:

```
grepme
grepmetoo
```

How to grep everything under "NAME" and remove else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```bsh
command | cut -d' ' -f1 | tail -n+2
# or if delimiter is tab
command | cut -f1 | tail -n+2

# or
command | awk 'NR>1{print $1}'

# or
command | csvcut -d' ' -c NAME | tail -n+2
# or if delimiter is tab
command | csvcut -t -c NAME | tail -n+2
```

---

As you mention `grep`, you could also use

```bsh
command | grep -o '^[^[:blank:]]*' | tail -n+2
```

But I'd prefer one of the above as it is way more difficult to read.
The `cut` solution has the best performance, `csvcut` by far the worst.

Comment: Nice simple solution! Marked as correct!

Answer (score 1):

Consider outputting only the desired data to begin with:

```
kubectl get pods --no-headers=true -o custom-columns=":metadata.name"
```

or

```
kubectl get pods --no-headers=true -o name
```

(Pulled from [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35797906/4957508) and the [kubectl overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/))

Comment: Good solution, but since I asked for grep I did'nt make as correct, but great command still!